# I have problem with my visual studio code when I run command "npm run dev"

Tags: npm

PS E:\travel\vuecore course files> npm run dev
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path E:\travel\vuecore course files\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\travel\vuecore course files\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Van Hung\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-12-25T15_43_05_830Z-debug.log

Comment: It looks like there's no `package.json` on that path. **enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\travel\vuecore course files\package.json'**